# Can't Focus Textbox when mouse click vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple textboxes and cursor moved when tap enter key.And I made to not focus with mouse click in following code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Const WM_MOUSEFIRST As Integer =  &H200
    Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer =  &H201
    Const WM_LBUTTONUP As Integer =  &H202
    .
    .
    .

    Dim ownForm As Form = Me.FindForm()

    If Not ownForm IsNothing AndAlso Not ownForm.ActiveControl is Me Then
        If(m.Msg = WM_MOUSEFIRST OrElse _
           m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN OrElse _
           m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONUP OrElse _
           .
           .
           .)Then
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        EndIf
    Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    EndIf
End Sub
```

I wrote above code in common file to can access from others forms. So here comes the problem, I want to focus some textboxes with mouse click. How should I write. I can't modify above code becasue this is common.So please give me advice how to write to appropriate this situation.

I tried this code and it doesn't focus:

```
Private Sub txt_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txt.MouseDown
    txt.Focus()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: You cannot because `MouseDown` is never triggered in your control as you are suppressing it in the `WndProc`, which gets the message first.

Comment: Except MouseDown, Is there any other way to focus some textbox in this situation?